# What am I missing here? It's supposed to read a double and calculate the average of all the doubles entered and ends when Double.NaN is returned

Tags: java, methods

1. Write a sensor input method that takes as parameters a Scanner and a minimum
   allowable sensor value (a double). This method returns a double.
   This method must read a double as input from the Scanner. If this value is at or above
   the minimum value, then this value is returned by the method.
   If the value is below the minimum, then the method must prompt the user for another
   value. This is repeated until the minimum constraint is met.
   If the value is not a double (indicating that the user is done entering input), then the
   method must return Double.NaN. This is a special double value, Not-A-Number,
   that we will use here to indicate that there are no other values to be entered.
2. Write a main method that calls your sensor input method repeatedly until NaN is
   returned. When NaN is returned, your main method reports the mean of the entered
   values and halts.
   code:

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Mean 
   {
   public static double averageTemperature(Scanner input, double lowestTemp)
   {
       double temp = input.nextDouble();

       if(temp >= lowestTemp)                              
       return temp;

       while(temp < lowestTemp)                        
       {
           System.out.println("Invalid temperature. Please Re-enter: ");
           averageTemperature(input,lowestTemp);
       } 


       return Double.NaN;                              

   }
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       System.out.println("Enter the Temperature: ");  

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       double value = 0;

       double sum = 0;

       int i = 0;


      do{
           value = averageTemperature(input, -10);
           if(value != Double.NaN)
           {   
               sum += value;                           
               i++;                                    
           }
        }while(value != Double.NaN);                   


       double mean = sum / i;                          

       System.out.println("The average temperature is: " + mean);
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: your scanner does not work?

Comment: So what actually is happening? and why is that wrong?

Comment: Stack overflow is for coding questions, not help without assignments per se. Please ask a question which can be answered, not post your assignment / homework.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `NaN` in case of wrong temperature input in this piece of code.

```
    while(temp < lowestTemp)                        
{
    System.out.println("Invalid temperature. Please Re-enter: ");
    averageTemperature(input,lowestTemp);
} 


return Double.NaN;
```

What I think is that you have forgot to return proper temperature if such is provided, so there is missing `return` statement in line `averageTemperature(input,lowestTemp);` 
it should be something like this: `return averageTemperature(input,lowestTemp);`
In your case, even when you have provided correct input (but only after providing wrong first) you were returning `NaN` insteed of correct temperature.